# According to the Geneva Convention, what must a nation do to Prisoners of War if it doesn't have enough food for them?

Tags: armed-conflict, geneva-convention

During wars food is often in short supply, for both civilians and military members. What does the Geneva Convention suggest countries should do if there aren't enough food supplies for Prisoners of War? Should they be released? And what should the country do about future prisoners of war - simply refuse them the right to surrender?

The question is inspired by Ukraine's struggle to secure enough food for its cities during the current conflict.

Answer (score 21):

Feed them as well as the own troops. That section starts with

> Article 25
> Prisoners of war shall be quartered under conditions as favourable as those for the forces of the Detaining Power who are billeted in the same area. [...]

Of course there is also

> Article 26
> The basic daily food rations shall be sufficient in quantity, quality and variety to keep prisoners of war in good health and to prevent loss of weight or the development of nutritional deficiencies. [...]

So in a besieged city with POW, rations must be shared fairly. Note that it is a human rights violation not to feed civilians, too.

Comment: This essentially means you need to make sure before you start your war that your logistics train is able to keep up with the prisoners you are making and the infrastructure you are destroying. Failing to do so is technically illegal. Whether you care about that is another question entirely …

Comment: @JörgWMittag, for those who start a war of aggression, what is one more violation?

Comment: *"So in a besieged city with POW, rations must be shared fairly. Note that it is a human rights violation not to feed civilians, too."* - this means that such a besieged city has the legal obligation to surrender once supplies run low, otherwise it is committing human rights violations?

Comment: @vsz in practice I suspect that it means that the forces laying siege have a legal obligation to permit the distribution of humanitarian aid to the besieged population.  How that would work in the absence of a party providing humanitarian aid, I have no idea.  If this is correct, it certainly undermines the concept of "siege" in a fairly fundamental way.

Comment: @phoog : and the main purpose of a siege is to cut off the defenders from supplies, thereby forcing them to surrender. Otherwise it wouldn't be a siege, it would be an assault. And if the defenders are allowed to get supplies from the outside, they could last out basically indefinitely.

Comment: Presumably an organisation like the Red Cross would provide humanitarian aid in most circumstances, although this is not an excuse for failing to feed/care for POWs.

Comment: @phoog another possibility with similar issues is of course for the besieger to permit the evacuation of  non-combatants

Comment: @vsz hypothetically, if the Red Cross could supply food, but no one could supply weapons, the besieger could exhaust the defender's ammunition with little more than probing attacks, then stroll in and take over - still a siege, but one that's a bit less awful for the civilians and even defending troops

Comment: @vsz It's arguable that laying siege to a (predominantly) civilian objective is a potential war crime in the first place, because you're going to cause civilians to suffer and starve. Claiming that it's the besieged city's authorities' fault for not surrendering like they should have before it got there is the kind of disingenuous rhetoric that invaders love to use to justify their war criming.

Comment: @Shadur Causing civilians to starve is just being ratified as war crime in itself: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amendments_to_the_Rome_Statute_of_the_International_Criminal_Court#Amendment_to_article_8_(starvation_of_civilians)_(2019)

Comment: @PMF Expect a lot of arguing to and fro in practice between the attacker and defender as to whose fault it is that the civilians are starving. Also, "Not of an international character" and "intentional" give entirely too much wiggle room to make it a useful statement.

Comment: @Shadur Maybe, yes. But who is besieging whom is quite obvious in most situations. It will probably have to come down to a court having to decide whether a siege of a city is already a war crime.

Comment: @Shadur this disingenuous rhetoric reminds me of the thug on the train who, after a bit of a shoving match with someone else, demanded that the other person not stand too close by saying "don't make me hit you."

Comment: @vsz If the the city is responsible for food distribution, its job is to distribute what it has evenly/fairly. Not having food isn't a crime, rather a really bad circumstance. It would be the same if the city was too poor to afford rations. It might be a violation if not surrendering went against the people's wishes (see UDHR Art21), beyond that, unless city officials are actively blocking supplies coming in or being distributed, I don't see a crime.

Comment: All these comments are a good reflection of the fundamental issue of the Geneva Convention: it's trying to make something that is inhumane by design (war) more "humane".

Comment: @Shadur the problem with your argument is that cities are always the main objectives, especially if the war is territorial. The warring parties want to control territory, and to do that they need to control the major cities. If you made "taking cities" a war crime, then everything would be a war crime and no one would care, it would be just as useless as if you said "shooting at an enemy soldier is a war crime". The purpose of having some actions declared war crimes is so that militaries can agree to not commit them while still being able to pursue their objectives. Otherwise they won't care.